# \[ .... \] or $$ for mathmode in LaTeX; which is preferable?

Tags: math-mode, displaystyle

Which one is better to use if you want mathmode in LaTeX, `\[ ... \]` or `$$...$$`? My teacher said that `\[ ... \]` is better, but he did not give an argument why. Is there one?

I'd be interested for reasons to prefer the former.